# Zend Framework 3 Pass Parameters from Controller to View Helper in Layout View

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3, view-helpers

How can I pass parameters to a view helper in layout view from a controller, or pass parameters to view helper somehow else in Zend Framework 3?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?  A view helper helps the view, so you typically pass parameters from there.  What are you trying to access a view helper from a controller for?

Comment: I have some view helpers in root layout.phtml and I need to pass them some arguments from controller

Comment: It is out of controller content view model scope view helpers

Comment: It is common view helpers for all pages with unique variables values  from each controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass parameters from a controller to a view helper in the layout view, you want to pass the parameter from the controller to the layout, and then call the view helper in the layout using the parameter it got from the controller.

```
// in the controller

$this->layout()->myParameter = 'foo';
```

then

```
// in the layout view

// set a parameter value for cases where a controller doesn't pass a parameter
$myParameterValue = ( isset($this->myParameter)) ? $this->myParameter : null ); 

echo $this->myViewHelper($myParameterValue);
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you so match